# Search by value in a multimap

Tags: c++, multimap

Considering a multimap `multimap<int,pair<int,int>> edges`, could anybody help me in how to search the location of a given pair (e.g. make_pair(1,2)) in `edges`? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing better than linear search using standard algorithm `std::find_if`.:)

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int>> edges = 
    { 
        { 1, { 1, 1 } }, { 2,{ 2, 2 } }, { 3, { 3, 3 } }
    };


    auto it = std::find_if( edges.begin(), edges.end(),
              [p = std::make_pair( 2, 2 )]( const auto &value )
              {
                return value.second == p; 
              });

              std::cout << it->second.first << ' ' 
                        << it->second.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 2
```

Or if your compiler does not support such a record of a lambda expression then you can rewrite it the following way

```
auto p = std::make_pair( 2, 2 );

auto it = std::find_if( edges.begin(), edges.end(),
          [&]( const auto &value )
          {
            return value.second == p; 
          });

          std::cout << it->second.first << ' ' 
                    << it->second.second << std::endl;
```

Comment: Could you please write the statement what I should use?

Comment: Oh, thank you! This page isn't updated automatically. :(

Answer (score 0):

`std::multimap` only indexes by its `Key`. You can search by value though, but that will be a linear search (not anywhere as efficient as searching by key). I suggest you checkout [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) and [*Boost.MultiIndex*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html). Nonetheless, to search by key, you could do:

```
template<typename Map, typename Val = typename Map::value_type>
auto find_by_key(Map& mp, Val val){
    return std::find_if(mp.begin(), mp.end(), [](auto& kv){ return kv.second == val; });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Suppose, that 10 belongs to the pair (1,2) (and possibly to other pairs, too).  Could you please project your solution onto this case, i.e. search for (1,2) according to 10?